# Which of these is the correct if statement?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

In the following pseudocode, what percentage raise will an employee in Department 3 receive?

```
if department < 2 then
 raise = SMALL_RAISE
endif
if department < 6 then
raise = MEDIUM_RAISE
endif
if department < 10
raise = BIG_RAISE
endif
```

A: SMALL_RAISE

B: MEDIUM_RAISE

C: BIG_RAISE

D: Impossible to tell

I chose medium raise because department < 6 is the first true statement within that block. Well according to my teacher, its big raise. Why is it big raise?
edit:

EDIT: Then why is this example medium raise? big raise is still the last true test.

In the following pseudocode, what percentage raise will an employee in Department 8 receive?

```
if department < 5 then
raise = SMALL_RAISE
else
if department < 14 then
  raise = MEDIUM_RAISE
   else
  if department < 9
     raise = BIG_RAISE
  endif
 endif
endif
```

Comment: Why dont you try it?

Comment: This pseudo code is a 'chain' of IF/ELSE statements, so only one statement will be executed. In your original question, the IF statements are independent of one another, hence the third statement overrides the result from second one.

Comment: First one is list of independent IF statements, so all 3 will be executed, and value from 2nd IF will be overwritten by 3rd one. In second one, it's else if statement, so when it matches < 14, it basically won't go to < 9

Answer (score 3):

The answer is `C` BIG_RAISE, while `3` is less than `6` it is also less than `10` and that is the final test condition (the `if` conditions lack `else`).

```
if department < 2 then   
 raise = SMALL_RAISE     /* <-- block not entered, 3 is not < 2 */
endif                    

if department < 6 then   /*     3 is less than 6 */
 raise = MEDIUM_RAISE    /* <-- block runs and raise is set. */
endif                    

if department < 10       /*     3 is less than 10 so the block */
 raise = BIG_RAISE       /* <-- runs and raise is set again. */
endif
```

Comment: Nevermind I understand

Answer (score 2):

The second `IF` statement will be evaluated as true and `raise` will be set to `MEDIUM_RAISE`. However, this will be overridden by third `IF` statement and eventually `raise = BIG_RAISE`. So in the end, the answer is c (`raise = BIG_RAISE`)

Comment: Nevermind I udnerstand

Answer (score 1):

I used c# but it should clear your confusion.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var department = 3;
    string raise = "NO RAISE";
    if (department < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SMALL_RAISE");
        raise = "SMALL_RAISE";
    }

    if (department < 6)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MEDIUM_RAISE");
        raise = "MEDIUM_RAISE";
    }

    if (department < 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BIG_RAISE");
        raise = "BIG_RAISE";
    }
}
```

The code above outputs

```
MEDIUM_RAISE
BIG_RAISE
```

Answer (score 0):

BIG_RAISE,off course 8 smaller than 14,and 8 is also smaller than 9,end if the first,the procedure into the second if.so the answer is BIG_RAISE.